# What is the nature of the relationship between Augustus Steranko & Ilsa Grunt?

Tags: plot-explanation, if-looks-could-kill

In the 1991 film "[**If Looks Could Kill**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_Looks_Could_Kill_(film))", the antagonists are businessman Augustus Steranko ([Roger Rees](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0715953/?ref_=nv_sr_1)) and his associate Ilsa Grunt ([Linda Hunt](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001373/?ref_=nv_sr_1)). Throughout the film, the two show no signs of a romantic relationship, yet Grunt appears to be jealous of Steranko's mistress. In addition, Grunt consistently defers to Steranko much as an employee would to their boss. However, at the formal party taking place during the film's climax, Grunt greets the party guests with the following dialogue:

> Good evening, ladies & gentlemen. Augustus and I are very proud and honored to welcome you.

This makes it sound like they are publicly a couple, or perhaps brother & sister. However, the wikipedia article I linked to above says that Ilsa Grunt is the surrogate mother of Augustus - which is odd given the apparent closeness of their ages. I'm also not aware of any dialogue in the film which would give that impression.

**What is the actual nature of this relationship, and where in the film do we find out?**

Comment: HA HA HA... He's actually a year older than she is. It's not "apparent closeness". It's possible that the wiki article writer got a bit creative. The IMDb page says "Together they proceed to Steranko's chateau only to be captured by Steranko's **assistant** Ilsa Grunt (Linda Hunt) in the process."